# xamarin issue uploading app to play store with android 12 edit AndroidManifest

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-play

I dont understand what AndroidManifest file ,I need to edit with this `exported` flag for this error to go away in the play store. I have edit the file in the `Properties` and the `obj\Debug\130\android` but it will not remove this warning message

Error message

`You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="30302" android:versionName="3.0.2" package="xxx.xxxx.nccn" android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_READ" />
  <uses-permission android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_WRITE" />
  <application android:label="Patient Guides" android:largeHeap="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:icon="@drawable/appicon" android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:allowBackup="true" android:debuggable="false" android:extractNativeLibs="true">
    <activity android:label="Patient Guides" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" android:name="crc6487aefd3090b7ea5e.SplashActivity" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="PatientGuidelinesApp.Droid" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:name="crc64b130862e93296c81.MainActivity" android:exported="false"/>
    <receiver android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" android:name="crc64a93b901f58a35d0f.PushReceiver" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.mediaparts.nccn" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="crc64a93b901f58a35d0f.TokenService" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="crc64396a3fe5f8138e3f.KeepAliveService" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:label="Essentials Battery Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.BatteryBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:label="Essentials Energy Saver Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.EnergySaverBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:label="Essentials Connectivity Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <provider android:authorities="XXX.XXXfileProvider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="xamarin.essentials.fileProvider">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/xamarin_essentials_fileprovider_file_paths" />
    </provider>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PowerSaveModeBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <provider android:name="mono.android.MultiDexLoader" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999999" android:authorities="XXX.XXXmono.android.MultiDexLoader.__mono_init__" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999998" android:authorities="XXX.XXXmono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <!--
             FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:exported="false" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:name="com.microsoft.appcenter.distribute.DeepLinkActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:host="updates" android:path="/" android:scheme="appcenter" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.microsoft.appcenter.distribute.DownloadManagerReceiver" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <service android:name="com.onesignal.GcmIntentService" android:exported="false" />
    <service android:name="com.onesignal.GcmIntentJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" android:exported="false" />
    <service android:name="com.onesignal.RestoreJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" android:exported="false" />
    <service android:name="com.onesignal.RestoreKickoffJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" android:exported="false" />
    <service android:name="com.onesignal.SyncService" android:stopWithTask="true" android:exported="false" />
    <service android:name="com.onesignal.SyncJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" android:exported="false" />
    <activity android:name="com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:exported="false" />
    <service android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationRestoreService" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <provider android:name="com.pdftron.pdfnet.PDFNetInitializer" android:authorities="XXX.XXXpdftron-pdfnet" android:exported="false" />
    <provider android:name="com.pdftron.pdf.utils.PDFTronToolsInitializer" android:authorities="XXX.XXXpdftron-tools" android:exported="false" />
    <provider android:name="com.pdftron.pdfnet.PDFNetInitializer" android:authorities="XXX.XXXpdftron-pdfnet" p6:node="remove" xmlns:p6="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:exported="false"/>
    <provider android:name="com.pdftron.pdf.utils.ShareProvider" android:authorities="XXX.XXXpdftron.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
    <provider android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" android:authorities="XXX.XXXfirebaseinitprovider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" />
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" android:exported="false">
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="false" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!--
             FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!--
             FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity android:name="com.microsoft.appcenter.distribute.DeepLinkActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:host="updates" android:path="/" android:scheme="appcenter" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.microsoft.appcenter.distribute.DownloadManagerReceiver" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedReceiver" android:exported="false"/>
    <service android:name="com.onesignal.GcmIntentService" android:exported="false"/>
    <service android:name="com.onesignal.GcmIntentJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" android:exported="false"/>
    <service android:name="com.onesignal.RestoreJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" android:exported="false"/>
    <service android:name="com.onesignal.RestoreKickoffJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" android:exported="false"/>
    <service android:name="com.onesignal.SyncService" android:stopWithTask="true" android:exported="false"/>
    <service android:name="com.onesignal.SyncJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" android:exported="false"/>
    <activity android:name="com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:exported="false"/>
    <service android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationRestoreService" android:exported="false"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <provider android:name="com.pdftron.pdfnet.PDFNetInitializer" android:authorities="XXX.XXXpdftron-pdfnet" android:exported="false" />
    <provider android:name="com.pdftron.pdf.utils.PDFTronToolsInitializer" android:authorities="XXX.XXXpdftron-tools" android:exported="false" />
    <provider android:name="com.pdftron.pdfnet.PDFNetInitializer" android:authorities="XXX.XXXpdftron-pdfnet" p6:node="remove" xmlns:p6="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:exported="false"/>
    <provider android:name="com.pdftron.pdf.utils.ShareProvider" android:authorities="XXX.XXXpdftron.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
    <provider android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" android:authorities="XXX.XXXfirebaseinitprovider" android:initOrder="100" android:exported="false"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!--
             FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The error message you provided indicates that you have components (activities, services, receivers) in your AndroidManifest.xml file that have intent filters, but the android:exported property is not set explicitly. This is causing an issue because starting from Android 12, components with intent filters must have the android:exported property explicitly defined.

To resolve this issue, you need to go through your manifest file and set the android:exported property for each component that has an intent filter. Based on the Android 12 behavior, you have two options for setting this property: true or false.

```
<activity android:name="init.SplashActivity" android:exported="false"> // true or false
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Yes I understand that did you look at the attached file

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be are looking at the wrong manifest. You shouldn't need to manually add android:exported='false' as the build will do it automatically for you, but to see it (read it) you need to look in obj folder either debug or release. There you will see how it is added.

The other glaring mistake for Android 13 is WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. You've got no hope of using that for a normal app in Android 13.

That is one hell of manifest.